# Using a custom trained word2vec model

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec

I have a corpus is the form of a CSV file or text file. I want to use it to train a word2vec model. Then I want to use the trained model to vectorize a CSV file that contains class and class description, ie each class will correspond to a vector. How to do it using python?

I have so far looked into training a custom word2vec model, but all of them are giving the vector of a single word as output. I want to pass a description and get a single vector as output

Comment: `I want to pass a description and get a single vector as output` Sounds like you want a sentence vectorizer rather than a word vectorizer.

Comment: @NickODell yes, how can I proceed with that. I am new in NLP, please help if possible

Answer (score 0):

If all you have is word-vectors, and you want a vector for a longer multiword text, one quick & simple option is to just average together the word-vectors for all the words in the longer text.

In the Gensim library, there's a helper method `.get_mean_vector()` on the `KeyedVectors` model class (for storing/accessing a set of word-vectors) that lets your provide a list-of-words, and get back the average of all their word-vectors.

Docs: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.KeyedVectors.get_mean_vector

Example:

```py
    mean_vector = w2v_model.get_mean_vector(list_of_words)
```

Such a multiword text vector, from an average of word-vectors, may be pretty good for broad 'topicality' purposes, but inherently *can't* capture the kinds of meaning created by careful ordering/grammatical arrangements – since it is completely oblivious to ordering.

(As just one example, the impact of the word `'not'` on how huans perceive a text varies greatly based on its position: is it reversing a single adjective, or a an entire predicate, or something else? A simple average of all words can't ue the `'not'` to flip the right thing, it just mixes-in a little bit of `'not'`'s most generic influence. You need more sophisticated deep/recurrent models, which understand ordering/grammar, for such fine-grained modeling.)